# fonts stopped working in font-awesome 4.7 version

Tags: css, html, fonts, font-awesome-4

I am using font-awesome version 4.7. Everything was fine few days back but suddenly few fonts stopped working. Here is the list:

1.fa-television
   2.fa-handshake-o
   3.fa-product-hunt
Can anyone please help me to understand why and how can I fix that? By putting version 5 does not help very much looks like need to make many changes.

```css
.fa-lg {
  font-size: 17px !important;
}

.icon-background2 {
  color: #496360 !important;
}
```

```html
<li onclick="roomName()" style="top:7px" class="usercss1">
  <a href="#" style="color:#fff;padding: 5px;">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background2"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-television fa-stack-1x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="collaboration" style="font-size:13px !important;font-weight: 600;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Please find the above code that I am using but it is not displaying television icon as it works for other icons.Please look at the below screenshot

[image].

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @MrLister I have updated the code with an example.Thanks

Comment: Works for me... https://jsfiddle.net/e9msLL0t/ Are you sure the font is loading correctly?

Comment: @MrLister sorry but does not work for me.I have attached the screenshot.Thanks

Comment: Can you point to a website that produces that screenshot?

Comment: @Mr Lister Please visit https://dusterboard.com/ you will have to signup for this.Click on the login from top and signup.

Comment: You are using fontawesome 4.3.0 on that page. The TV icon was added in version 4.4.

Comment: I think you have checked only main page.It is like bad from the side I am using 4.3 in the main page and 4.7 in other pages and television icon is used in other pages.If there is any way I can share my cred to just login I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting#some-icons-dont-show-up) is a link to Font Awesome's Github page. There are various reasons why this could be happening and this link gives you a good starting point to trouble shoot the problem. It could be caused by any css resets, or any css that overrides icon tags. It could possibly be the inline css you are using. Or it could be an extension or plugin within your browser or an ad blocker. Have you checked your console as the page loads and verified that the font files are being loaded properly? Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Ok I added more detail as to what the link suggests could be the issue. Thanks for the heads up.